# Specifying 1.9 mode with JRuby and rbenv

Tags: jruby, rbenv

I have 2 applications, one that needs to run JRuby 1.6.5 in 1.8 mode and another that needs to run JRuby 1.6.7 in 1.9 mode.  Is it possible to specify within the application that I want the one application to run in 1.9 mode without having to explicitly set the JRUBY_OPTS environment variable.  Within .rvmrc, I could do the following:

```
proj_1_8 version of .rvmrc
unset JRUBY_OPTS
rvm use jruby-1.6.5@proj_1_8

proj_1_9 version of .rvmrc
export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
rvm use jruby-1.6.7@proj_1_9
```

Is there anyway I can automatically get the mode set without having to manually set/unset the environment variable whenever I switch between projects?

Comment: Looks like this will accomplish what I want:

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-vars

Answer (score 3):

As D3mon-1stVFW suggested...

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-vars will help.

```
$ ruby-app-dir> jruby --version
jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-05-01 26e08ba) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_33) [darwin-i386-java]

$ ruby-app-dir> ## Install rbenv-vars as indicated in Github

$ ruby-app-dir> cat .rbenv-vars
JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9

$ ruby-app-dir> jruby --version
jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-05-01 26e08ba) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_33) [darwin-i386-java]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#readme).

```
$ chruby jruby --1.9
$ jruby --version
jruby 1.7.0 (1.9.3p203) 2012-10-22 ff1ebbe on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_09-icedtea-mockbuild_2012_10_17_15_53-b00 [linux-amd64]
$ chruby jruby --1.8
jruby 1.7.0 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2012-10-22 ff1ebbe on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_09-icedtea-mockbuild_2012_10_17_15_53-b00 [linux-amd64]
```